# Oracle Linux R9 as Virtual Machine at Google Cloud gives fail on image creation: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release"

Tags: oraclelinux, google-cloud-compute-engine

I am going to host Tenable Security Center on a virtual machine. The virtual machine will run at Google Cloud and has to be of the type Oracle Linux as it is required by Teanble Security Center.

Google Cloud does not have any images ready for Tenable Security Center, so I need to build one myself.

This is the procedure that I have done:

**Create image**

- Start VMWare Player
- Create a new virtual machine and installed Oracle Linux
- Shut down virtual machine

**Upload image**

- Upload all files in the virtual machine folder to a Google Cloud Bucket

**Import image**

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/imagesAdd?project=tenable-security-center
- Name: oracle-linux-image
- Source: Virtual Disk file (from bucket)
- Operation system on virtual disk: Detect operation system
- Install guest packages: on
- Family: blank
- Description: blank

**Logs**

```
[inspect-disk.attach-input-disk]: 2023-06-14T09:00:59Z AttachDisks: Attaching disk "projects/tenable-security-center/zones/europe-north1-a/disks/disk-xzjqq" to instance "projects/tenable-security-center/zones/europe-north1-a/instances/run-inspection-inspect-disk-h68rv".
[inspect-disk]: 2023-06-14T09:01:02Z Step "attach-input-disk" (AttachDisks) successfully finished.
[inspect-disk.wait-for-signal]: 2023-06-14T09:01:09Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "run-inspection-inspect-disk-h68rv": StatusMatch found: "Status: Executing command: ['lsblk', '--noheadings', '--output=NAME', '--paths', '--list', '--nodeps', '-e7']"
[inspect-disk.wait-for-signal]: 2023-06-14T09:01:09Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "run-inspection-inspect-disk-h68rv": StatusMatch found: "Status: /dev/sda"
[inspect-disk]: 2023-06-14T09:01:19Z Error running workflow: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "run-inspection-inspect-disk-h68rv": "Failed:"
[inspect-disk]: 2023-06-14T09:01:19Z Workflow "inspect-disk" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[inspect-disk]: 2023-06-14T09:02:08Z Workflow "inspect-disk" finished cleanup.
[import-image]: 2023-06-14T09:02:08Z Disk inspection error=failed to inspect zones/europe-north1-a/disks/disk-xzjqq: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "run-inspection-inspect-disk-h68rv": "Failed:"
[import-image]: 2023-06-14T09:02:10Z could not detect operating system. Please re-import with the operating system specified. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#bootable
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

What causes this error? What did I do wrong?

Comment: The operating system was not detected. My guess is that the boot area of the disk is incorrect or corrupted. You can try to mount the disk on a different instance and debug the disk pay and boot sections.